# Successor axiom in Robinson arithmetic

Tags: induction, first-order-logic, peano-axioms

The successor axioms of Robinson Arithmetic (Q) are:

1. $\forall x\,(Sx\neq0)$
2. $\forall x\forall y\,[(Sx=Sy)\rightarrow x=y]$
3. $\forall y\,[y=0\;\lor\;\exists x\,(Sx=y)]$

Note that 3. differs from the following Successor Axiom of Peano Arithmetic:

4. $\forall x\exists y\,(y=Sx)$

Question: is there a proof in Q (in classical first-order logic with identity) of 4. ?

I take it that the canonical answer is "yes", since, e.g., Q is $\Sigma_1$ complete.  But the only argument for this of which I am aware uses (instances of) induction in the metatheory.  So, I wonder if one can actually point to a (first-order)) derivation in Q of 4.
If not, how, if at all, could a believer in Q, but no more, justify belief that every number has a successor?

Comment: 3 in this Robinson Arithmetic is more of a predecessor axiom.

Comment: I think the first two axioms implicitly take it for granted that every number has a successor otherwise the symbol $Sx$ would not have any meaning. Anyway, the axiom 4. cannot be deduced by using the previous ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Statement (4) is *not* an axiom of PA in any of its usual formulations, because it is not needed.  Indeed, statement (4) is provable in first-order logic (with equality) from no axioms at all.  By reflexivity of equality, $Sx=Sx$, from which you can deduce $\exists y(y=Sx)$ by existential introduction.

The point here is that merely having the symbol $S$ in your first-order language as a unary function symbol means that $S$ represents a function that can be applied to any element of your structure to obtain another element.  This doesn't have to be stated as an axiom; it is implicit in the syntactic rules (specifically, the fact that for any term $x$, $Sx$ is a term).

Comment: Thanks, Eric.  To confirm, the following is the concrete proof you envision?  Sx = Sx [Logic of Identity] / ∃y(y=Sx) [Existential Introduction] / ∀x∃y(y=Sx) [Universal Generalization]

Comment: Sure; the exact details may depend on what proof system you are using.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks very much!